# Product attribute in Google's product search result description

Tags: product, attributes, search, seo, google

1. How to show the product attribute in google's product search result description? Particularly, I want to show the final price of the product.
2. Please check the below-attached image in which amazon managed to show the product's attributes. Similar to this I want to show the **final price of the product**. [image]

Comment: You can send anything what you want, but you first must have to send attribute and value which you want to be searched in google, as you have send above attributes same way you can send or try here official google docs
**https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/7052112?hl=en**

Tell me do you want to do this in magento?